# Control alignment

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

got a wpf window with two controls listview and lisbox(shown always at a height of window).

```
 <Grid >            
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="230"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">                
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <local:LeftSideListView Grid.Row="0"/>
        </Grid>

        <local:RightSideiveView Grid.Column="1"/>           

    </Grid>
```

Here I wanted the listview height to be auto -so I kept `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`
but when listview has to show many items ,it shows only few items rest are truncated.

How can I show a listview with its height **auto** and same time if more items present (> size of window )- show a scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is what I wanted..

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <local:UC_FvExplorer VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set binding between the LeftSideListView MaxHeight and your "LayoutRoot" grid.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">            
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="230"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">                
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:LeftSideListView MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualHeight}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>

    <local:RightSideiveView Grid.Column="1"/>           

</Grid>
```

If the LeftSideListView height will be greater than the LayoutRoot height its height would be changed to the MaxHeight value and the verticalscrollbar will be shown.